# Is it insecure to temporarily save user's data in a session while they register?

Tags: passwords, session-management

My plan is to save the registration, as they go along so if they close the page by accident they will still have all of there information saved so they can continue it again.

But my question is it secure to save there data (like passwords) in plain-text on a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation on this is to protect the password in the same way that you would after the signup is completed.

For registered users you should be storing only a salted and hashed version of the password. For users going through the signup flow, you should do the same. In a typical signup flow, the user is requested to choose a password and type it twice. As soon as you have verified that both typed passwords are identical, you can compute a salted hash of the password.

The salted hash of the password can be stored in the session for the rest of the signup flow.

Answer (score 2):

It is never ok to store a user's password in plain text. Let them retype their password.

Perhaps letting their browser's form filler remember the data will work better. Those are generally careful about doing the right things with passwords.